# How to configure session.save_path and fix "phpMyAdmin Error during session start"?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to launch phpMyAdmin, but still encounter the same error.

In `php.ini` a property is `session.save_path = "/tmp"`, so maybe I just don't understand where I have to place this folder. Trying to run this on Apache, folder "phpMyAdmin is located in htdocs.

[image: Error]

Comment: did the permission of /tmp is 777 ?